# When does equality hold in $\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^nb_k^2\bigg)\ge\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k\bigg)^2$

Tags: inequality, summation, vectors

In the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:$$\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^nb_k^2\bigg)\ge\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k\bigg)^2$$If $a=<a_1,a_2,...,a_n>$ and $b=<b_1,b_2,...,b_n>$ then $(a\cdot b)^2\le ||a||^2||b||^2$

When does equality occur?

Is the answer when $a$ and $b$ are linear independent? Am I even on the right track?

Comment: Yes, but instead of linearly independent, try the opposite $a = Cb$.

Comment: When looking at the case for an equality, always try inserting $0$ first.

Comment: The condition for equality follows directly from a proof of CS (see e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proof)) and reads: $x = y\frac{(x\cdot y)}{||y||^2}$ i.e. $x=Cy$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are proportional -
if there is a $c$ such that
$a_i = c b_i$
for all $i$.